# PrimeNg DataTable not working with Angular 5

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, angular5

I am using PrimeNg datatable with editable option true. I am getting following error:

**Error:**

```
ERROR in Error at D:/Project/ui/src/app/pages/admin/components/dashboard/dashboard.component.html(38,31):  ("lumn.isSortab
le" [style]="column.columnStyle?column.columnStyle:{}">
                    <template [ERROR ->]let-col let-row="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
                      <textarea *ngIf="column.isEditab")
Error at D:/Project/ui/src/app/pages/admin/components/dashboard/dashboard.component.html(38,39):  ("ortable" [style]="colu
mn.columnStyle?column.columnStyle:{}">
                    <template let-col [ERROR ->]let-row="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
                      <textarea *ngIf="column.isEditableAsText")
```

**DataTable HTML:**

```
<p-dataTable *ngIf="showTable()" [value]="tableConfig.data" [dataKey]="'id'" [rowStyleClass]="highLightUnsavedRow" [lazy]="true" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" [responsive]="true" [totalRecords]="getTotalRecords()" (onLazyLoad)="onRowEvent($event)" [(selection)]="selectedRows"
                    (onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" (onRowUnselect)="onRowUnselect($event)" [editable]="true" (onHeaderCheckboxToggle)="onHeaderCheckboxToggle($event)" (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)">
                    <p-header>Header</p-header>
                    <p-column *ngIf="tableConfig.isMultiSelect" [style]="tableConfig.multiSelectColStyle?tableConfig.multiSelectColStyle:{'width':'38px'}" selectionMode="multiple"></p-column>
                    <p-column *ngFor="let column of tableConfig.columns" field="{{column.fieldName}}" header="{{column.columnTitle?column.columnTitle:column.fieldName}}" [filter]="column.isFilterable" [editable]="column.isEditable" [sortable]="column.isSortable" [style]="column.columnStyle?column.columnStyle:{}">
                        <template let-col let-row="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
                          <textarea *ngIf="column.isEditableAsText" class="edit-field" [(ngModel)]="row[col.field]" (change)="onTableEditTextBoxChange(row,col.field,row[col.field])"></textarea>
                          <p-dropdown *ngIf="column.isEditableAsDropDown" class="edit-field" autoWidth="false" [style]="column.editFieldStyle?column.editFieldStyle:{}" [(ngModel)]="row[col.field]" [options]="column.editDropDownOptions"></p-dropdown>
                        </template>
                    </p-column>
                </p-dataTable>
```

The problem is with the attributes **let-col** and **let-row="rowData"** of following tag:

```
<template let-col let-row="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
```

If I remove these two attributes, then the build issue disappears but the table renders with 0 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`ng-template`** has to be used in Angular 5

```
<ng-template let-col let-row="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
```

It is now an error as it was deprecated in angular 4.x

### Note:

You can still use `<template>` by setting the `enableLegacyTemplate` flag in the compliler options to `true` which  can be configured as

In the **`main.ts`**

```
const compilerOptions: CompilerOptions = {
  enableLegacyTemplate: true
};
```

Use the value in the module as

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule,compilerOptions)
```